# How to enlarge the reponse range of SeekBar?

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I placed Fragments in a ViewPager, and one of them contains a SeekBar. Both the SeekBar and its thumb are very small. It always result page changing when trying dragging it. So how can I  enlarge the reponse range of SeekBar? Thanks a lot. :)